# Typo3 Repository update

Tags: fluid, typo3-extensions

I just start to develop a new extension, where one image is included.
If I using the add function from repository the image will be correct saved.
But when I using the edit controller function to change the image file und use than the repository update function, the old image will be not overwritten, but an additional image will be added.
I also tried to use the combination of remove/add instead of update. The result was the same. This I absolutly don't understand!
I am using Typo3 8.7.9. and have used the Extension-Builder, the version in the git.

Can anybody give me a hint, where the problem could be?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove first `FAL object`. You can do this like below.

in your controller file You create function for remove old image Fal object.

```
/**
 * remove ImageObject
 *
 * @param \vendor\ExtensionKey\Domain\Model\Modelname $object
 * @return void
 */
public function removeImageObject(\vendor\ExtensionKey\Domain\Model\Modelname $object) {
    if(!empty($object->getImage())){
        $resourceFactory = GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Resource\\ResourceFactory');
        $fileReferenceObject = $resourceFactory->getFileReferenceObject($events->getImage()->getUid());
        $fileWasDeleted = $fileReferenceObject->getOriginalFile()->delete();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Pravin,
I understand, that I have first to delete the Filereference (sys_file_reference). From my Recipe class (\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\DomainObject\AbstractEntity) I already get the filereference object. Therefore I should able to use it to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

I understand, that I have first to delete the Filereference (sys_file_reference). From my Recipe class (\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\DomainObject\AbstractEntity) I already get the filereference object. Therefore I should able to use it to delete it.
I have added the following function.

```
/**
 * Deletes the recipePic Filereference
 * 
 * @param \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference $recipePic
 * @return void
 */
public function delRecipePic(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference $recipePic)
{
    $this->recipePic->getOriginalFile()->delete();
    $this->recipePic->delete();
}
```

But both calls are not working. What I am doing wrong?